# Bash Comparing two types of outputs with long strings

Tags: bash, sh

I have a known good configuration of x.yml.  That configuration consists of 30 lines of code with only 8 lines NOT commented out, two of those lines NOT commented out are completely blank.
So my results look like

This is an output from
`grep -v '#' /mnt/data/x.yml`

```
node.name: 123
path.data: "/mnt/data/data"
pipeline.workers: 4
pipeline.batch.size: 250


http.port: 9600-9700
path.logs: "/mnt/data/logs"
```

Or very similar to that at least.

How would I take that string and compare it to the output from another x.yml if I was using it for troubleshooting?

Would I just compare two strings like:

```
if [ "$goodYML" = "$outputYML" ]; then
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "not equal"
fi
```

and declare that whole string above as a variable and then how would I set the output of my grep to a string?

Comment: `var=$( grep ... )`

Comment: not needed for 8 lines but you can pipe into a hashing program to get a fixed size output. eg `var=$( grep ... | sha256sum )`

Comment: It's not clear what your criteria are. Is it okay for two lines to switch places within the same structure, for example? Does the solution need to cope correctly with YAML references? In the limit, normalize the two inputs somehow (maybe using `yq` or another YAML parser) and then compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use process substitution

```
diff <(grep -v '^#' /mnt/data/x.yml) <(grep -v '^#' /mnt/data/y.yml)
```

Any commands can be put between the `<( YOUR COMMAND HERE )`

---

**EDIT**

Since your file is not local, you could do:

```
diff <(grep -v '^#' /mnt/data/x.yml) <(ssh user@host grep -v '^#' /mnt/data/y.yml)
```

All pertinent details should be in the question.

Comment: The known good yml is not on the same system, thus I would be bringing over the variable information.  I think the utilization of a check sum maybe my best bet

Comment: @Nathan if it's not on your computer then how can you get it into a variable and compare like `"$goodYML" = "$outputYML"`? And you should use `grep -v '^#'` to make sure the lines are really comments, not a string containing `#`

Comment: @phuclv I was taking a known good output from another computer.  I see the confusion, my apologies for not explaining that.    I am sure there is not # in the string of text, that would not be good